# What's different about Safari.app in OS X 10.9.1 and Safari.app on the Recovery HD?

Tags: macos, safari, recovery

Having mounted the Recovery HD<sup>1</sup>, I MD5'd the Safari binary from the `BaseSystem.dmg` and MD5'd the Safari binary from my OS X Mavericks 10.9.1 install:

- `/Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari`:

  669623eb8c35daf0a1a90b4895943723
- `/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari`:

  668065167a8b3b9ad3034bdba400a9dd

What's been changed in Safari.app on the Recovery HD?

<sub><sup>1</sup> Mounted using:</sub>

```
diskutil mount Recovery\ HD && hdiutil mount /Volumes/Recovery\ HD/com.apple.recovery.boot/BaseSystem.dmg
```

Comment: This might need build version levels to make sense later. I'm presuming you asked this soon after Mavericks was out and 10.9 _(.0)_ was the version and 10.9.1 was not yet released?

Comment: 10.9.1 was released on December 16th. So it was already out. Mavericks GM 10.9.0 shipped with Safari 7.0, 10.9.1 came with Safari 7.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OSX 10.9.1  :

OSX's Safari is a 7.0.1 (Build `9537.73.11`, MD5 Hash  `668065167a8b3b9ad3034bdba400a9dd`)

Base System's Safari is a 7.0 (Build `9537.71`, MD5 Hash `669623eb8c35daf0a1a90b4895943723`)

So `/Applications/Safari` differs on the Recovery HD.

---

On OSX 10.9.2 :

- The System Safari  : 
  v 7.0.2, Build `9537.74.9` : MD5 Hash `1d2c91b644b46f41bfb54c214600a688`
- The Recovery partition Safari : 
  v 7.0, Build `9537.71`, MD5 Hash `669623eb8c35daf0a1a90b4895943723`

Conclusion : Apple's doesn't seem to update the Recovery Partition when OSX gets updated !

Comment: Any chance you would re-run your tests and document what versions are in place on a system that has been updated to 10.9.2?

Comment: See my update !

Comment: Thanks. I don't think it's necessarily a bad thing that Recovery HD is stable. It will be interesting to see if/when it ever does get modified.