# Deleted Safari and now I cannot get it back. Mavericks

Tags: macos, safari

I deleted my Safari browser and now I would like to download it again but it seems that this option is not as easy to be done. I'm running OS X Mavericks at the moment, and there is no download for Safari on the Apple page except for those before OS X Lion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get back a system file after deleting it from my Mac?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116611/how-can-i-get-back-a-system-file-after-deleting-it-from-my-mac)

Comment: Depending on how you came to delete safari, we can offer some help. Your safest bet is to re-download the Mavericks Installer from App Store, but perhaps if you edit some details in the question we can guide you better than the linked question with several options.

Comment: …especially since [Safari on the Recovery HD is probably old](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115173/whats-different-about-safari-app-in-os-x-and-safari-app-on-the-recovery-hd) so the 'grab the file from the Recovery HD' trick probably isn't ideal. — cc @bmike

Answer (score 7):

Safari gets reinstalled:

- Sometimes when you download and [install a Combo Updater](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1726).
- Always when you [reinstall the OS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-x-mavericks/id675248567?mt=12).

You could also use a tool like [Pacifist](http://charlessoft.com/) to get the app from the install package (or Time Machine from your backup), but it depends on how you lost the app whether you want to go in like a surgeon or have the deluxe treatment. Unless you are sure you can use Pacifist, I'd start with the Combo and then move to the normal installer.

Answer (score 3):

You can copy Safari from the recovery partition:

```
diskutil mount Recovery\ HD
hdiutil mount /Volumes/Recovery\ HD/com.apple.recovery.boot/BaseSystem.dmg
cp -R /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System/Applications/Safari.app /Applications
```

Alternatively redownload an OS X installer from App Store and then use [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com):

[image]

Comment: So far on 10.9, the Recovery HD is unpatched and most people are at 10.9.2 with [several Safari security updates](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6145). Although I'd prefer the Pacifist route myself, nothing here is untrue. Also, I haven't done the work to determine if the fixes on "10.9.2 Safari" are really framework fixes that could reside outside /Applications entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install [Safari 7.1](http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/52/24/031-05306/ejsgyg0iatqosbvktr9jlamsm28k0yfoaf/Safari7.1Mavericks.pkg) manually, directly from Apple. This is the same link the App Store uses to check for updates. (Note that if you install that package on anything other than Mavericks — assuming Installer would even permit such a thing to happen — you will probably cause more harm than good. That package is for Mavericks only, as the filename says.)

Source: [The SU catalog](http://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-10.9-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog) (search it for "Safari7.1" to verify the .pkg link, if you'd like).